# Laravel 5.6 - Cannot change the uploaded file name in $request, temporary name is inserted in the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

I created a form with `file` and uploads the file and stores the data in the database very well. The problem is, I need to store the modified file name in the database but the Laravel stores the temporary name in the database. This is the code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('file');
    $imageName = time().rand(1,100).$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('uploads'),$imageName);
    $request['file'] = $imageName;
    //$request->file = $imageName;
    $im = new Image($request->all());
    $this->user->images()->save($im);
}
```

I tried to modify the `file` manually but it didn't work. This the `dd` of `$request`

[image]

But still the temporary file name is inserted in to database.

---

This is the table and `file` column must have the name of the file

[image]

As you see the file name I provided is not in the `file` column, the temporary is in there

Comment: Is the name of file stored in uploads folder is correct ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes

Comment: After adding new image name to request just dump the request array like this, dd($request->all()) and add the output please

Comment: I did this and added in the image

Comment: I've added my answer, have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason why its happen:

As you have printed `$request` array on screen, the uploaded file name has changed as per your desired name,

but problem arises when you use `$request->all()` method, see below the `all()` method in [Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d93d0faea59015b92562c6146d16b923f383a245/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L163-L178)

```
public function all($keys = null)
    {
        $input = array_replace_recursive($this->input(), $this->allFiles());

        if (! $keys) {
            return $input;
        }

        $results = [];

        foreach (is_array($keys) ? $keys : func_get_args() as $key) {
            Arr::set($results, $key, Arr::get($input, $key));
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

The above method **replaces the normal input keys with file input keys if both have same name**, means if you have `$request['image']` and `$request->file('image')` then after calling `$request->all()` your `$request['image']` is bound to replaced by `$request->file('image')`.

So what to do if you don't want to replace it automatically like here you want to get newly uploaded file name in `$request['file']` instead of tmp\php23sf.tmp,

### Solution:

**one workaround is to use different name in file input and db field name**, lets take your example:

1. You have database table field `file` for storing uploaded filename so use name `userfile` or any other name in file input as `<input type="file" name="userfile">`
2. Then after it in your controller use same code as you have used with different name:

see below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('userfile');
    $imageName = time().rand(1,100).$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('uploads'),$imageName);
    $request['file'] = $imageName;
    $im = new Image($request->all());
    $this->user->images()->save($im);
}
```

It will work definitely, correct me if i am wrong or ask me anything if you want further info, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change name from:

`<input name="file" type="file"/>`

to:

`<input name="upload_file" type="file"/>`

Answer (score 0):

as [@Haritsinh Gohil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56791695/6685807) described

> As you have printed $request array on screen, the uploaded file name
> has changed as per your desired name,
>
> but problem arises when you use $request->all() method, see below the
> all() method in Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php

However, you can keep the input with the name file and make

```
    $image = $request->file('file');
    $imageName = time().rand(1,100).$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('uploads'),$imageName);
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['file'] = $imageName;
    $im = new Image($data);
    $this->user->images()->save($im)
```

Answer (score -1):

After looking at the output you have provided, I think here is your mistake.

```
$imageName = time().rand(1,100).$image->getClientOriginalName();
```

You have to add Original Extension instead of Original Name like this,

```
$imageName = time().rand(1,100).$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: You didn't get the problem. It is not important what the `$imageName` is, set this to `1.jpg` for example. I can't insert this in to the database. The temporary name which is something like `C:\xampp\tmp\phpAC28.tmp` is inserted in the table

Comment: @Drupalist please add your db table structure, strange problem though

Comment: I added the table